# Removing List view for ArrayField Django

Tags: python, django

How would I display the ArrayField in a template without the quotes and brackets. currently it looks like ['django']. I would like to have it look like: django

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: how you are accessing that list obj in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the first value:

```
{{ object.arrya_field_name.0 }}
```

or with filter

```
{{ object.arrya_field_name|first }}
```

If you need all values, use loop:

```
{% for item in object.arrya_field_name %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

or filter

```
{{ object.arrya_field_name|join:", " }}
```